# Basic questions about AppExchange licensing (consumer perspective)

Tags: appexchange

Maybe there's an FAQ that I haven't found, so these questions may seem basic...

If I subscribe to an app on a AppExchange that costs $x/user/mo, do I get to choose how many users I'm buying it for?  Or is it for all users?  Or does the publisher decide?

If I can choose, is there somewhere in Setup where I can assign which users get the license for the app?  Am I able to re-assign licenses from one user to another?  Or does this depend on an app's licensing model?

Comment: Amusingly, there isn't a good SF-authored FAQ for subscribers (consumers of apps). Take a look at [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_checkout_pricing_models.htm), it covers your first question from the app developer's perspective and mostly answers it. Your 2nd question: this is done by you from inside SF org: see [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_package_user_licenses.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISVs (AppExchange Publishers) can choose to enable per-site (all users in your org) or per-user licensing, or both. They can also use a pricing matrix to give customers a discount for subscribing to a large number of licenses, or for non-profits, can choose to give out free trials for any duration they desire, etc.

The only legal requirement they are contractually bound to is to pay a fraction of all licence revenue to salesforce.com in exchange for the various benefits they get being licensed on the AppExchange. Aside from that, they are free to do pretty much anything they want to do with their app, since it is their product.

You, as a consumer, get to choose from the available pricing models that the ISV offers, and how many licenses you need, if not getting a site-wide license. If you have a limited number of licenses, you can freely assign and reassign those licenses as you see fit, at any time, for any reason. You can do this from the User Detail screen in Setup, or by using a Data Loader tool, or by Apex Code, etc.

Note that most ISVs do require a contractual commitment; you can't typically just buy licenses for one month. Typical agreements are for 1-, 2-, and 3-year commitments, and sometimes the pricing matrix has a built-in discount for longer terms.